# CopyFileEx() fails with ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION for file created by CreateFile()

Tags: c, winapi, temp

I want to create a temporary copy of a DLL file in the temp folder, and have it deleted on application exit. Due to unrelated reasons too long to explain, I cannot simply remove the file at the end of the function/script that creates it.

I tried using `CreateFile()` with `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`, but when I try to copy the original file to this file, I get `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`.

Here's my code:

```
BOOL CopySuccess = 0;

if ((_waccess(TempFilePath, 0)) == -1) {
    printf("Temp copy \'%ls\' not found, creating copy now\n", TempFilePath);
    CreateFileW(TempFilePath, (GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE), (FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE), NULL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, NULL);
    CopySuccess = CopyFileExW(OriFilePath, TempFilePath, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    if (!CopySuccess)
    {
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Copy dll to temp file failed"));
    }
}
```

AFAIK, I used the correct flags in the `CreateFile()` call to enable shared access to the file.

What am I doing wrong/what is an alternative approach?

I need the logic to maintain this structure. Without going into details, for reasons that escape my control, this script will be run around 10 times per second, so I need a way to copy the file just once, then have it deleted once the application exits, due to error, ctrl-c event, or normal exit.

---

As a reply to the comments:

I tried writing the contents of the original file to the tempfile created with `CreateFile()`. This didn't work because the handle returned by `CreateFile()` is not valid to use as a library (library handles are of type HMODULE). Closing the handle then re-opening it not a possibility, as closing all handles to the file causes it to be deleted as per the `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` flag.

I figured the issue would be on CopyFile()'s side. I didn't think of writing my own function, so instead I tackled the problem the following way:

There's one specific var that increases by a fixed amount in every iteration of the main script, so I wrote an if statement that would check:

- If the copy of the dll already existed
- If the current value of the variable was below the 2nd iteration value

If both conditions were met, the already existing copies of the dlls would be deleted. Similarly, the dlls are only attempted to be copied in the 1st iteration of the main script.

This is not an actual answer to the question, but a way to circumvent it. I'll give a try to writing my own version of CopyFile(). If I succeed and it behaves as I intend it to behave, I'll post the code and an explanation as an answer here. Thanks all!

Comment: My ***guess*** is that "error 32" is some kind of access denied error. Which will happen because you have the destination file already opened. Copy the file, *then* open it.

Comment: Please confirm that you get the error with `CopyFileExW`? But, how do you know you've got this error? There is no call to `GetLastError`.

Comment: of course your call `CreateFileW(TempFilePath)` is reason why `CopyFileExW` to `TempFilePath` fail with `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`. remove `CreateFileW`. this anyway will not do what you want

Comment: Doesn't `CreateFileW` open the file, keep it open ("in use by [another] process") and return its handle?

Comment: I am using a custom function to handle errors, ErrorExit. As far as I understood the docs, yes CreateFile creates the file and keeps it open. But If I give it it write/read and share attributes, it should be usable by child processes. From the docs: "To enable a process to share a file or device while another process has the file or device open, use a compatible combination of one or more of the following values."

Comment: @ghylander - you not think about - with which share access `CopyFileExW` try create the file (hint - with 0). as result and `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` you can not use copyfile here, but you can manual read data from OriFilePath and write it to handle returned by first call to OriFilePath.

Comment: @ghylander "*which share access `CopyFileExW` try create the file (hint - with 0)*" - in other words, `CopyFileExW()` creates the file for *exclusive* access, so if anyone has the file opened *for any reason* then the copy fails.

Comment: You could write your own version `CopyFileExW` which isn't really complicated, then you can use `CreateFileW` with whatever mode you want and then you write into the handle return by `CreateFileW`.